# Typed and untyped delegates

Tags: c#, lambda

What is the difference between

```
var propertyResolver = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, object>>(expr, arg).Compile();
string name = (string)propertyResolver(p);
```

and

```
var propertyResolver = Expression.Lambda(expr, arg).Compile();
string name = (string)propertyResolver(p);
```

In the second case there is some kind of "untyped" delegates.

What is that?

EDIT:

```
ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(p.GetType(), "x");
Expression expr = Expression.Property(arg, "Name");
```

Comment: What's the type of `expr` here?

Comment: In particular, does the second version compile for you?

Comment: Both compile. ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(p.GetType(), "x");
Expression expr = Expression.Property(arg, "Name");

Comment: @devhedgehog The second expression *shouldn't* compile.  There's something that you're not showing us.

Comment: I'm surprised that the expression `propertyResolver(p)` compiles in the second case.

Comment: They compile fine. I think is Lambda(expr, new[] {arg}) but they do compile. Lambda may be used without generic types. Just Lambda(...).

Comment: @devhedgehog Yes, you can call `Lambda` without generic arguments, but you won't get back a delegate that can be invoked as you have shown.  Copying your code directly it does not compile, as expected.  Either this *isn't* the code you're using, or you're mistaken about it compiling.

Comment: Thanks for the good comments Jon and Servy!

Comment: Oh right. The second one doesnt compile. But why? What is happening in the background?

Comment: @devhedgehog Read the compiler error.  It will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I could call propertyResolver.DynamicInvoke(p) still the question is the difference between those two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code is a call to [`Expression.Lambda<TDelegate>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340145%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which returns an [`Expression<TDelegate>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335710%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which has a [`Compile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345362%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method returning `TDelegate`. So the type of `propertyResolver` in your case is `Func<Person, Object>`.

The second code is a call to the non-generic [`Expression.Lambda`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268052%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which returns a [`LambdaExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  This has a [`Compile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356928%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that just returns `Delegate`. So the type of `propertyResolver` in your case is `Delegate` - which is why `propertyResolver(p)` won't compile.

Comment: Ok so far so good I get your point but I could call DynamicInvoke on second one right? The point is I can invoke both no matter if I made a mistake in my code. Lets call my code pseudo code. I apologize for making the mistake in my code. Still my question is what is the difference between those Func<t, t1> delegates and normal simple System.Delegate. Both may be invoked. Why is Func faster? Is it because somehow func knows the type and those simple plain delegates doesnt?

Comment: @devhedgehog: Yes, you can if you want. The difference is that you've got a concrete, compile-time-known type in the `Func<,>` example. It's like the difference between using `string x = "foo"; int y = x.Length;` and `dynamic x = "foo"; int y = x.Length;`. Note that it's pretty rare to use plain `Delegate` in general.

Comment: Ok. I get that. Thanks. Btw how could I do something like this: Expression.Lambda<Func<value.GetType>>(..)?

Comment: @devhedgehog: You can call `Expression.Lambda(Type, Expression, IEnumerable<ParameterExpression>)` which will create a delegate of the right type - but you still won't know that type at compile time.

Comment: How do I call later that delegate of right type? With InvokeDynamic() That is slow. I want something fast :) :)

Comment: @devhedgehog: If you want something fast, use types known at compile time. Fundamentally we don't know nearly enough about your situation to give you good advice. I've answered the question you originally posted - if you want advice on a related matter, you should ask a new question *with appropriate details*.

Comment: Ok here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841767/invoke-delegate-with-right-type

Comment: @devhedgehog: That doesn't give *nearly* enough information about the situation you're actually facing. If you don't give much context, there's very little scope for useful answers.

Comment: Its a common question isnt it. I have an method with one parameter type object. Anything can be set on that parameter. And I need to find the property with name "Info" of that parameter. Check it out again.

Comment: @devhedgehog: It's a common question in lots of different contexts, each of which can have a different answer. That's why context matters. Is there any reason you can't take the type as a generic type parameter, for example? *Please* update the question with more information.

Comment: Ok I get it. I edited the question. Take a look at it please.