# Invoke Delegate With Right Type

Tags: c#, linq

I have a parameter of type object. Anything can be set on that parameter. And I need to find the property with a certain name in that parameter. If it exists of course.

I need something like this (pseudo code):

```
ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(parameter.GetType(), "x");
Expression expr = Expression.Property(arg, "Info");

var propertyResolver = Expression.Lambda<Func<parameter.GetType, object>>(expr, arg).Compile();
```

There is already the method `Expression.Lambda(Type, Expression, ...)

But that returns System.Delegate back to me and I need the Func<>.

What can I do to achieve this?

Thanks in advance guys.

Here is a demo:

```
class Program
{
    private Func<object, object> func;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // lets say in this case the parameter is person but it could be anything
        Person parameter = new Person();

        ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(parameter.GetType(), "x");
        Expression expr = Expression.Property(arg, "Name");
        var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<parameter.GetType, object>>(expr, arg).Compile();
    }
}

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

After I created my function I have to call it at least 1000 times in an for loop inside another method therefore DynamicInvoke is not an option here. Its too slow. I try it out.

Comment: What *are* your performance limitations? Can your method be made generic so that the type of `parameter` is available as a type parameter instead? When and how are you calling the delegate? (Presumably not just with `parameter`...)

Comment: The method itself must be implemented because its from an interface so I cant change anything there but I could call another methods inside. Performance is very important here. Therefore I will need to store the created function locally.

Comment: Please provide all this information - and anything else you can tell us *in the question*. We shouldn't have to drag it out of you one bit at a time.

Comment: There is no more. Its just that. What info do you need more? I edited my question and posted you a demo. Its not much really. Its a simple qustion but complicated to solve. Take a look at the demo please.

Comment: There is no reason to downvote this. The question doesnt need or has much code. There is nothing more I can post to you guys.

Comment: You clearly can - you can tell us about the interface that you're trying to implement... presumably one part preparing and one part executing? You can tell us about whether that interface is owned by you (and could therefore be changed) or whether it's some system interface. You could tell us what your exact performance requirements are (rather than just "very important"). All kinds of things.

Comment: If you reject answers for reasons they couldn't understand from your question, clearly you didn't include enough context. If there's more of it, tell us. No one is going to want to answer you just to get told 'no, because <something you never told us!>'. In a simple app like that, displaying things onscreen is going to be slower than compiling an expression. It's all so arbitrary that we cannot really help you.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I get you but the point is not changing the requirements or my interface or all my project just to make this work. The point solving this by given requirements. I cant change the project anyway. I cant change the interface. I cant change the requirements here. I created that small demo to make things simple for you guys. But you do not like it. That is all what I need help with. I need to have a Func<> with types provided at runtime. I respect your efforts just from my point of view the demo explain it all. Stop changing the requirements.I edited the question.If you need more ask me

Comment: From my point of view that is what you guys would need to help me out. IF you need more please ask me and I ll try to create another demo. I cannot change requirements. Its not in my hands. I have to deal with it.

Comment: But you didn't *tell us* the requirements. You knew you were implementing an interface, but you didn't tell us that nor have you *still* shown us that interface. You still haven't told us how fast it has to be (what your performance requirements are) so we would have no way of checking whether or not a particular solution is fast *enough*. I'm afraid at this point I give up... I can't waste my time just continually asking for information which should have been present from the start. Maybe someone else will be able to help you.

Comment: Well what is the point when I tell you that interface name is IValueConverter and its from Microsoft. Method name is Convert(..) And its being called on each entity but I have 10k entities. There are no performance limits. With reflection its slow so I figured it would speed things up with Func<>. The method itself is not so much interesting. It could be any method. I could pass the value to other methods called from the interface method. It would hold the same instance. I dont see it what you need more so I guess tell me what exactly you need more. I cant upload all project.

Comment: @Magus No need to run that extreme. I wish I could remove this question right now. This is not a question about how to post questions. Lol. People who want to help will find a way to post a solution or provide me helpful ideas like Konrad did but not like what you both doing here. Help me or leave it. But dont tear the question down like you and Jon are doing. If you dont understand the question ask for more. If you dont know how to solve the question dont ask to change requirements. If you feel there are no enough info then leave it. Somebody else who knows will provide me with helpful hints.

Comment: The problem with that outlook is that this site exists for posterity. People need to be able to see your questions and answers and use them to solve their problems. If we don't understand your problem, it's entirely your own fault. We don't to change the requirements, we just want to know what they are. Telling someone their answer is invalid for a reason you didn't tell them previously is quite offensive. The one who made the mistake was you. Take responsibility for yourself and the future. A vague question with vague answers helps no one.

Comment: Where is the mistake? Which part of my code you dont understand?

Comment: We asked you what your performance needs are, since you said it needs to be fast. K, how fast? By knowing that, we can determine whether or not reflection will work, or be able to design other solutions, maybe even involving IL. You've been asked at least four times how fast you want it, and you keep telling us we're changing some kind of mystical requirements. We just want yours. Any others you can think of. Anything that might make you reflexively shout NO again.

Comment: Read my question again. I said: After I created my function I have to call it at least 1000 times in an for loop inside another therefore DynamicInvoke is not an option here. Its too slow. I try it out. DynamicInvoke is Reflection my friend.

Comment: And yet we don't see that for loop or the outer one. There's a lot we don't see. If any of that could possibly matter, could make the difference between an accept or downvote, you need to tell us. It's just a matter of decency. Look at it this way: Your question was phrased so badly that Jon Skeet, one of the most knowledgeable people in the C# world, who gives answers in far more detail than anyone usually needs, gave up on you.

Comment: I've thought of at least two possible options. However, I can't tell whether or not they'll be fast enough, as you'd given us no performance requirements. We know that `DynamicInvoke` isn't fast enough, but we don't know what *would* be fast enough. I also don't know whether either of them would be suitable in terms of exactly how you'd use them (as they involve creating slightly different delegates to the one you've currently got). Given your earlier question, either of them *might* be appropriate, but I'm not going to waste time writing and testing code that may not be appropriate.

Comment: Dear Jon Skeet I have tried the solution with DynamicInvoke and like you say its not fast enough. Therefore I want to try the Func<> version. Therefore like I say in my question I need to know how to make func<> with types defined at runtime. Let me try it out with func first, let me test it for you. You guys dont worry about how fast it is just tell me how can I do this with Func<>. Thats the question. I am asking how to do it with Func. Func<> is faster than DynamicInvoke so no matter how faster as long its a bit faster I am happy. As long I gain any performance win I am happy.

Comment: This question has been *immensely* frustrating to answer. I've jotted down a quick answer, but I haven't even tried to compile either solution, as I think it entirely likely that you'll say it doesn't meet some other requirement. I find it amazing that you can tell that `DynamicInvoke` isn't fast enough, but something even a *bit* faster would make you happy. If you have no good measure of "fast enough" then you really, *really* need to get one.

Comment: Dear Jon Skeet I am measuring performance per item with Stopwatch. Any millisecond would help. Since I have 10k items that would be a performance gain of 10 seconds. That is what I ment with anyhow faster would make me happy. I appologize for everything. I see its time to remember your name. Or I should stick a sticker on my pc sayin "what would Jon Skeet do?" :) :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options to consider:

- Use dynamic typing to call a generic method which will return you a `Func<object, object>` which you can use later by wrapping up an expression-tree-compiled delegate:

  ```
  public Func<Object, Object> CreateFunc(object sampleValue)
  {
      dynamic dynamicValue = sampleValue;
      return CreateFuncImpl(dynamicValue); // Dynamic type inference
  }

  private Func<Object, Object> CreateFuncImpl<T>(T sampleValue)
  {
      // You could use Delegate.CreateDelegate as another option - 
      // you don't need expression trees here
      var parameter = Expression.Parameter(parameter.GetType(), "x");
      var expression = Expression.Property(arg, "Name");
      var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(expression, parameter)
                           .Compile();
      return (object actualValue) => func((T) actualValue);
  }
  ```
- Wrap the property expression in a conversion expression in the expression tree:

  ```
  public Func<Object, Object> CreateFunc(object sampleValue)
  {
      var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "x");
      var conversion = Expression.Convert(parameter, sampleValue.GetType());
      var property = Expression.Property(conversion, "Name");
      return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(property, parameter)
                       .Compile();
  }
  ```

Both of these *assume* that you're doing the creation very rarely and then calling the delegate many times with values of the same type. They may or may not be what you need - it's hard to tell with weak requirements. They do require that the values you call the function with later are of the right type, of course.

Comment: Ok thanks. I ll test them out in a minute. May I ask which is faster of those two options in your opinion?

Comment: @devhedgehog: No idea - I haven't even compiled them. They may well be about the same. You'll find out when you try though :)

Comment: Ok test results are here. Jesus I feel like I should kiss your feet or something. The second one with coverting is the fastest. In fact it has the same time as `Func<Person, object> func = x => x.Name` has. Ok now I believe you are the the godfather of c#. I applogize for all the troubles. I couldnt understand why you guys need more info since I was just asking how to do it with funcs. I wanted to test it only with funcs. Its not in my hands to expose much about this project. Its pretty complicated wpf stuff going on in there and performance was bad. Thanks you helped me out alot.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will suits your needs:

```
Expression.Lambda(Type, Expression, IEnumerable<ParameterExpression>)
          .Compile()
          .DynamicInvoke(...)
```